# How can I change this "SELECT IN" to "EXISTS" query for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT au.*
  FROM account au
  WHERE au.id IN (
    SELECT fa.from_user_id
      FROM approvals fa
      WHERE fa.to_user_id = 1
      GROUP BY fa.from_user_id
   )
 ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC
 LIMIT 0, 18446744073709551615;
```

How can I change this to `EXISTS` instead of `IN()`?

Comment: What's the reason for the change?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `GROUP BY` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT au.* 
FROM account au 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM approvals fa 
   WHERE fa.to_user_id=1 
     AND fa.from_user_id = au.id
) 
ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC LIMIT 0, 18446744073709551615;
```